# Vagrant: Is there a Vagrant Share hook

Tags: magento, vagrant, vagrant-share

I am using Magento which creates its urls based on a `base_url`, what I want to achieve is to automate the modification of this `base_url` based on the url returned from Atlas when starting a Vagrant share session.

Looking into the vagrant documentation there seems to be Action Hooks for most actions vagrant up, provision, destroy etc but nothing for share.

Is anyone aware of any such hook that may be undocumented? or can anyone suggest an alternative method of automating the change in `base_url`.

it shouldn't make any difference but the `base_url` is a database record so my thoughts were to run a shell script with the SQL command to update this value when the hook was caught.